# HTTP request and condition in Swift 2

Tags: json, swift, http, nsarray

I'm new in Swift and I can't find the solution to this code :

```
func presentationlum() {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://raspberrypi.local/etatlum.php")!)

    let Session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    var JsonDict=NSArray()
    let dem = Session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        do{
            JsonDict = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0) )as! NSArray

        }
        print(JsonDict)

    })
    dem.resume()


    if JsonDict[0] as! String == "0"
    {
        print("it works !")
    }
    else
    {
        print("it works to !")
    }

}
```

When I built it I have a "Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT" error.
The Server send a Json_encode array with only `0` or `1` ( example : `["1","0","0","1","0"]`).
I just want to get this response and do conditions with it but I can't. 
Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing your answer before the blocks complete :

```
func presentationlum() {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://raspberrypi.local/etatlum.php")!)

    let Session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    var JsonDict : NSArray
    let dem = Session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        do{
           if  let _JsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions() )as? NSArray
          {
                JsonDict = _JsonDict
                if JsonDict[0] as! String == "0"{
                     print("it works !")
                 }else{
                      print("it works to !")
                }

          }else{
               print("Cannot parse JSON answer")
          }
        }catch {
         print("An Error as occurred : \(error)")
       }
         print(JsonDict)
    })
    dem.resume()
}
```